# Python modules run function from file

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have a python (2) project with this structure:

```
alerter
│   README.txt
│   __init__.py
│   __init__.pyc
│
└───lib
        Alarm.py
        Alarm.pyc
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
```

in `lib.__init__.py` I have a function that I want to call from `lib.Alarm.py`.
If I just call it in `Alarm.py` I get this error:

```
NameError: global name 'openDatabase' is not defined
```

Now I tried almost all imports at the top of the `lib.Alarm.py` file:

- `from lib import openDatabase`

  ```
  ERROR: ImportError: No module named lib
  ```
- `from alerter.lib import openDatabase`

  ```
  ERROR: ImportError: cannot import name openDatabase
  ```

Anyone an idea what I might try?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from alerter import lib
lib.openDatabase()
```

(You don't state your Python version, which could be relevant.)

Comment: Thanks for helping
The version is python2.
With this change, I get this error:
ImportError: cannot import name lib